# How do I fix a site after I removed a module?

Tags: wsod

I deleted a module without disabling and uninstalling it first.  Now I just get a blank white screen, but I don't see any error messages.  What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Download the module again. Place it in sites/all/modules, disable it, uninstall it and then delete again.

Comment: And that *still* might not be enough if there's a hardwired call to the module in a dependent module; some PHP-running textarea (Views globals, blocks, nodes); the theme...

Comment: OK, but the rest still stands :)

Answer (score 3):

Run the following query.

```
select info from system where name = 'module_name';
```

You will get a blob. Within this blob look out for text after `version`. You can find the version of the module here.

Download this version of the module. Place it in `sites/all/modules` folder(you can also find out the previous location from the file-name field in system table), uninstall the module. Now delete the module.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer if the module implements an uninstall hook.

Answer (score 1):

Put the exact same version of the module back into your modules folder, disable and then uninstall it the correct way.

Comment: Hello. I don't quite understand *why* it should help, and *how*. Please consider expanding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL console or PHPMyAdmin:

> update system set status = 0 where name = 'MYMISSINGMODULE';

Clear cache and stay calm.

Comment: That's a bad thing. There might be something important being done in uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it back and then disable it and uninstall it again.

You need to supply some additional information:

- The version of Drupal (5,6,7,8?)
- The name and version of the module

I've previously restored the database of Drupal 6 to a site without all the modules and never got a blank page so it must of been a pretty important part of the site.

Are you sure you can't access the ?q=/admin page? Even if you can't access the rest of the site these pages maybe unaffected.